# How can I load images from second internal HD in Darktable on a Mac?

Tags: workflow, macintosh, darktable, os-x, filesystems

Since Aperture has stopped development, I have sought an open source alternative for my workflow. I am interested in Dark Table, but I can't navigate to my second internal HD. The file picker doesn't let me go higher than root on my OS drive. I am using OS X 10.10.3 on 2015 15" MBP and have a second internal HD installed using Optibay. How can I load my images into Darktable from the second internal HD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply needed to navigate to /Volumes to find the other mounted devices.